# TFSEC Summary Export Summary

Tags: linux, aws-codepipeline, tfsec

I am running TFSEC inside a pipeline.  I execute the following command to run TFSEC.

```
- tfsec -s --custom-check-dir ${CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR} > tfsec_static_code_analysis_summary_${PIPELINE_EXECUTION_ID}.txt
```

As you can see I am trying to export the results from TFSEC.  I already know that TFSEC has an output and I use that to get the csv.   The problem with the csv is if there is no errors it's blank.  This proves to be a problem with my organization.  The compromise is they are willing to take the Summary + the CSV as proof that it ran.  The command above is my attempt to export the summary which yields this result:

```
[0m  [1mtimings[0m
  ──────────────────────────────────────────
[0m[0m  [2mdisk i/o            [0m 221.427µs
[0m[0m  [2mparsing             [0m 3.293529ms
[0m[0m  [2madaptation          [0m 73.017µs
[0m[0m  [2mchecks              [0m 5.092385ms
[0m[0m  [2mtotal               [0m 8.680358ms
[0m
[0m  [1mcounts[0m
  ──────────────────────────────────────────
[0m[0m  [2mblocks              [0m 45
[0m[0m  [2mmodules             [0m 3
[0m[0m  [2mfiles               [0m 12
[0m
[0m  [1mresults[0m
  ──────────────────────────────────────────
[0m[0m  [2mignored             [0m 0
[0m[0m  [2mexcluded            [0m 0
[0m[0m  [2mcritical            [0m 0
[0m[0m  [2mhigh                [0m 0
[0m[0m  [2mmedium              [0m 0
[0m[0m  [2mlow                 [0m 0
[0m
[0m
[32m[1mNo problems detected!

[0m
```

From what i have read its common for Linux to mix text up.  I am trying to get my export to output into the format from the screenshot.

[image]

Not sure if anyone knows a command that i can use.  I have tried the following with no success:

```
- tfsec -s --custom-check-dir ${CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR} >> tfsec_static_code_analysis_summary_${PIPELINE_EXECUTION_ID}.txt

- tfsec -s --custom-check-dir ${CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR} | sed 's/^[ ]*[0-9\:\/ ]\+[ ]*//' | unix2dos >> tfsec_static_code_analysis_summary_${PIPELINE_EXECUTION_ID}.txt

- tfsec -s --custom-check-dir ${CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR} | tee -a tfsec_static_code_analysis_summary_${PIPELINE_EXECUTION_ID}.txt
```

Looking for any help here.

Answer (score 0):

Special thanks to my buddy who helped me out with this.  We ended up using the sed command to do the export which looks like this

```
 - tfsec -s --custom-check-dir ${CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR} | sed -e 's/\[[0-9;]*m//g' | sed -e 's/\x1b*//g' >> tfsec_static_code_analysis_summary_${PIPELINE_EXECUTION_ID}.txt
```

The first set of sed regex gets the format correct.  The second removes the escape markups in the export.

Hopefully this helps others out there!

Answer (score 0):

Using `--no-color` or `--no-colour` would have remove the encoding for colours.

Alternatively, you can use `-f text` to spit out basic text format.

Looks like you found a way in the end.